# Nested loops with dependent variables

Tags: algorithm, loops, for-loop, iteration

Suppose we have a following loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++)
      for (int k = j+1; k < n; k++)
         for (int l = 0; l < n; l++)
```

I understand that the first loop will loop **n** times.

I think that the second one is going to be run **(1/2) * (n^2 + n - 2)** times because we we'd need to calculate the sum from 2 to n, not from 1 to n.

However, I have no idea about the third and the fourth ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are (at least) two ways to understand the time complexity: the first involves noting that the three nested for-loops generate precisely all `3`-subsets of an `n`-set, and the second one is a "direct" approach.

#### Combinatorial argument

The first three for-loops choose precisely all `3`-subsets of an `n`-set, each `3`-subset exactly once (think about it). There are `(n choose 3) = O(n^3)` such subsets (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)). The innermost loop does `O(n)` work for each of `O(n^3)` iterations of the other three loops, so the total time is `O(n^4)`.

The three loops (without the innermost one) make exactly `n choose 3 = n!/(3!(n-3)!)` iterations. This is exactly `n*(n-1)*(n-2) / 6` iterations.

#### Direct argument

The innermost loop will execute `n` times regardless of the other loops, so the time complexity will be `O(n * f(n))`, where `f(n)` is the time complexity of other three loops if we remove the innermost one.

The two innermost loops (the `j`- and `k`-indexed ones) together take `O(i^2)` time. This is easy to see---it is the same as having a double-loop from `j=0` to `i-1` and `k=j` to `i-1`, so the time is  `O(1) + O(2) + ... + O(i) = O(i^2)`.

Because the outtermost loop goes from `i=0` to `n-1`, the total complexity is `n * (O(1^2) + O(2^2) + ... + O(n^2))`, which is `O(n * n^3)`: the outtermost loop (`i`-indexed) executes the double for-loop (`j`- and `k`-indexed) from `i=0` up to `i=n-1`.

We thus have `O(n^4)` total running time.

To get the exact number of iterations, you would have to compute a sum of terms `i*(i-1)/2 = (i^2-i)/2` for suitable `i`'s. Let's just the sums and divide by two in the end.

You can break this into two sums,

```
(1^2 + 2^2 + ...n-1) - (1 + 2 + ... + n-1) =
= n(n-1)(2n-1)/6 - n*(n-1)/2 =
= n*(n-1)(n-2)/3
```

Now we divide by two and get the result `n*(n-1)*(n-2)/6`. Exactly the same as above. (See [how to compute the sum of first `n` squares](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Sequence_of_Squares).)

Comment: Ok, I understand the thing about running time complexity, but what's the exact number of iterations that the nested loops have?

Comment: It's exactly `n choose 3`. This is `n! / (3!*(n-3)!)`, or, simplified, `n*(n-1)*(n-2)/6`.

Answer (score 0):

First loop will repeat n times and second loop will go for (n-1) times and third loop will loop through (n-2) times and the last loop will go for l times. At the end all of them will go for 
n*(n-1)*(n-2)*l 
times.